# Local files or remote server

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I've developed a desktop application(Accountant App). This application is going to import invoices data and do a lot of other things. All data will be stored on remote database (SQL Server). This app needs some 'pre loaded data' to work properly, like a list containing a bunch of cities etc. My question is: Is better to have this data (cities, states, zipcodes) stored in the remote database or is better to use xml, csv files and deploy them with each individual instance of the application? This data will be updated eventually. And this data will be used frequently by the users.

Comment: How big is the list?

Comment: 10.000 rows 4 columns.

Comment: This completely depends on the use and none-functional requirements, we need more details to be able to answer this.

Comment: For e.g. how often this data requires updates?

Comment: The user only uses this list of cities when registering. And it rarely needs to be updated.

Comment: Ok, is this list should be updated on the client as fast as possible or users could wait undisturbed until the next application version?

Comment: What about other data within you app? Where are their data stored? you want to store it in the same fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can either use an external file or store them in the database. I think storing it in the database is the better approach since you won't have to distribute another extra file and all of your data will be at one place.  Don't forget to seed the data every time you clear the database though.